migrate wordpress manually: website keeps forwarding to old url
I am trying to migrate an existing wordpress website without downtime manually
I have transferred the database and copied all files manually replacing the entire wordpress folder
I would like to test that everything is working but when I go to my new website ip all I get is a redirect to the current .com url so I cannot see what is going on
I tried changing the siteurl value in the database with the new vps ip but I still get a redirect
can't see any reference in wp-config.php
What am I missing please ?
wordpress is a docker image if that helps
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

